# How to get the Location Coordinates in the maps the map which is being open by below Url

Tags: ios

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?];

How to handle Pin location in the maps which is opened by the above url. I want to handle Pin location which is showing that I entered in search bar in the maps and I want the coordiantes of the location also.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want to add pin at location opened by URL?

Comment: can you add some more information

Comment: Yes,Exactly @kamaldeepsinghbhatia, and also I want to handle that Pin Location Action

Comment: Try to use `MKPointAnnotation` but you need to know coordination to place Pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `MKPointAnnotation` to add annotation (pin) at a particular location

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"Where am I?";
point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
```

for detail information use following links :

- [Annotation Example](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-drop-a-pin-on-map-with-mapkit-api/)
- [MKAnnotation Protocol Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/index.html)

Let me know if your question is diff.